# How to limit area in OpenLayers map?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm trying to use openlayers v3.4.0 to display some geo information.
My map is created like this:

```
    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})
            })

        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 1,
          minZoom: 1,
          projection: 'EPSG:3857'

        })
    });

var pl = new ol.layer.Vector({...});
map.addLayer(pl);
```

It displays information I need to show and everything would be Ok, but you can scroll infinitive amount to sides and marked information isn't painted if you scroll.
For example if I mark London (with point or polygon) and scroll map using mouse to right side until another UK is on the map, there is no mark on London.

So what I want to do is to limit preview area to 1 world, so you can't scroll. I found that "extent" should limit area, but could not find how to use it correctly.

Comment: Looks like you can use extent on layer and on view, not entirely perfect, but at least people should not be confused seeing some area and not seeing signs, that was there just a minute ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a given extent using `view.fitExtent()` method. Here is a sample: http://acanimal.github.io/thebookofopenlayers3/chapter01_03_fit_extent.html

This simply set a new extent, if you want to restrict to some area you must use the `constrain*` methods. You can also use the `min/maxZoom` and `min/maxResolution` to contrain zoom.